# Nio в java

Tags: java

Добрый день! Я новичок, третий день изучаю java. Возникла потребность работать с java.nio.file.* для получения атрибутов файлов и папок.

Пишу следующий код:

```
File file = new File(pach);
BasicFileAttributes attr = Files.getAttribute(file, BasicFileAttributes.class);

if (attr.creationTime() != null) {
   System.out.println("дата создания: " + attr.creationTime());
}
if (attr.lastAccessTime() != null) {
   System.out.println("дата последнего обращения: " + attr.lastAccessTime());
}
if (attr.lastModifiedTime() != null) {
   System.out.println("дата последнего изменения: " + attr.lastModifiedTime());
}

System.out.println("является папкой: " + attr.isDirectory());
System.out.println("прочее: " + attr.isOther());
System.out.println("обычный файл: " + attr.isRegularFile());
System.out.println("размер в байтах: " + attr.size());
```

Ошибка возникает на строке:

```
BasicFileAttributes attr = Files.getAttribute(file, BasicFileAttributes.class);
```

**Ошибка:** `The method readAttributes(Path, Class<A>, LinkOption...) in the Files is not applicable for the arguments (File, Class<BasicFileAttributes>);`

Пробовал заменить его на:

```
Files.getFileAttributeView(file.toPath(), BasicFileAttributeView.class).readAttributes();
```

такой же параметр там присутствует...

Как я понял число параметров не совпадает, что за загадочный парамерт LinkOption, откуда его брать?

Comment: BasicFileAttributes attr = Files.readAttributes(file.toPath(), BasicFileAttributes.class);

Answer (score 2):

```
package com.sevak_avet.Test;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.attribute.BasicFileAttributes;

public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    File file = new File("G:\\Ubuntu-13.04-desktop-amd64.iso");
    Path path = file.toPath();
    BasicFileAttributes fileAtr = Files.readAttributes(path, BasicFileAttributes.class);

    System.out.println(fileAtr.creationTime());
    System.out.println(fileAtr.lastAccessTime());
    System.out.println(fileAtr.lastModifiedTime());
    System.out.println(fileAtr.size() / (1024.0*1024));
}
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Покопался в доках, нашел пример использования FileVisitor в NIO:
PrintFile: класс, который обходит все папки, и если ей встречаются файлы, то складывает в переменную SIZE их размер

```
package com.sevak_avet.Test;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.FileVisitResult;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.SimpleFileVisitor;
import java.nio.file.attribute.BasicFileAttributes;

public class PrintFiles extends SimpleFileVisitor<Path> {
public static long SIZE;

@Override
public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attr) {
    if (attr.isSymbolicLink()) {
        System.out.format("Symbolic link: %s ", file);
    } else if (attr.isRegularFile()) {
        System.out.format("Regular file: %s ", file);
        SIZE += file.toFile().length();
    } else {
        System.out.format("Other: %s ", file);
    }
    System.out.println("(" + attr.size() + "bytes)");
    return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
}

@Override
public FileVisitResult postVisitDirectory(Path dir, IOException exc) {
    System.out.format("Directory: %s%n", dir);
    return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
}

@Override
public FileVisitResult visitFileFailed(Path file, IOException exc) {
    System.err.println(exc);
    return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
}
}
```

Пример использования:

```
package com.sevak_avet.Test;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;

public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    File file = new File("G:\\Фильмы");
    Path path = file.toPath();
    PrintFiles pf = new PrintFiles();
    Files.walkFileTree(path, pf);

    System.out.println(PrintFiles.SIZE / (1024.0 * 1024 * 1024)); //переводим в ГБ
}
}
```

Проверил на нескольких довольно крупных папках, считает быстро и точно)

Comment: У меня строка BasicFileAttributes fileAtr = Files.readAttributes(path, BasicFileAttributes.class); не прокатывает. Выдает ошибку, требует еще один параметр какой-то в readAttributes. А за код спасибо, поможет мне

Comment: Не знаю, у меня все работает отлично, проблема не в коде

Comment: Пишу так BasicFileAttributes attr = Files.readAttributes(file, BasicFileAttributes.class, LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS); А мне в ответ такая ошибка: The method getAttribute(Path, String, LinkOption...) in the type Files is not applicable for the arguments (File, Class<BasicFileAttributes>, LinkOption). Уже замучился с этой ошибкой, застрял в программировании из-за нее...

Comment: Может быть у меня урезанная версия Java какая-то в которой нету Enum<LinkOption>? Такое может быть?

Comment: java -version ?

Comment: Java Platform (JDK) 7u25. Качал тут: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html